# Why asp boilerplate says core and uses framework?

Tags: asp.net, .net

http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/ (APB) is a more or less popular site to get asp.net core mvc patterned project templates. Using it you can select »ASP.NET Core 1.0« template and they create a solution for you.

But digging into their project.json files I see they're requesting framework .NET 4.6.1 and NOT netstandard1.x. As of my understanding this is not .NET Core. It's .NET Framework.

Why is this? What's the »core« part of projects generated with APB?

Comment: ASP.NET Core is completely separate thing from .NET Core

Comment: Furthermore, ASP.NET Core can run on top of full .NET Framework or .NET Core.

Comment: Jesus! Thanks. Should I answer myself? Or would you?